# c# reference to a class even if it is eliminated - xamarin forms

Tags: c#, list, class, xamarin.forms

I deleted a class from my solution, and created a new one.
The old class, I deleted and no longer exists is called: DLR_User, while the new one, which is in the project is called: OBJ_User.

My problem is that visual studio, debugging, still refers to the old one, even if it no longer exists, and not to the new one.
I tried to clean the solution and to rebuild the entire solution, but without success.
How can I fix?

my code:

```
USR_User_ReturnList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.OBJ_User>>(indexof);
```

screenshots collected after reading, debug display:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot DLR_User collects me and not as I OBJ_User septum list.
I can not fix, help

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project and rebuild?

Comment: i have writed "I tried to clean the solution and to rebuild the entire solution" in the answer. yes i have tryed :)

Comment: Oh, oops. Sorry, missed that line :P

Comment: sometimes cleaning is not enough, but you should remove all bin/ and obj folders in your solution